# User models registered to Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm a beginner in Django. I'm trying to make data user-specific in the Django admin panel. For example, I have a model registered with admin called courses. I have two users user A and User B. When I create a course with User A, User B must not see that. How can I achieve that with Django, is it something with sessions? If there are any keywords to search in google relevant to this please mention Thanks all,

Answer (score 1):

What I came up with is using Django's [List View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview). This class-based view shows the information specifically for a user and there are no ways for other people to view this information as there are **no primary keys** or anything. The context are retrieved from `request.user` or something that you passed into your `get_context_data`.

Comment: Will it work with the Django admin panel because I have no custom build template to render these data. I have only the Course model and User model

Comment: right now I'm not focusing about views and URLs I just want to make user A data independent from user B. Simply if user A add some data based on the model user B should not see data added by User A.

Comment: I was just wondering whether you could do that in the admin panel as it didn't and won't provide much flexibility. What made you stick to the admin panel though?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm just experimenting whether I can do that with the admin panel without making any other templates and views to render course details and adding students to those courses. Even I can add students to courses but they are not independent of other users

Comment: I believe, as long as you aren't forcing yourself you use the admin panel, my solution could work. One way to get around this is to create an app and have it share the same URL as the admin panel, although this makes you prone to bugs and conflicts and all sorts of trouble.

Comment: Ok mate I'll go in your way thanks for the solution